# How to add a CardView to a RecyclerView list

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

Looking to add a generic `CardView` to the top of an empty `RecyclerView` list by clicking on the "+" icon that is on the app's main menu.  Clicking "+" again will move the initial `CardView` down and the next generic `CardView` will be added to the top of the list.

Below is the portion of the `MainActivity.java` file:

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id  = item.getItemId();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.action_new:
                if (mAdapter != null) {
                addItem?
                mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
            }
            return true;
            case R.id.action_remove:
                if (mAdapter != null && mAdapter.getItemCount() > 0) {
                    mAdapter.removeItem(mAdapter.getItemAt(0));
                }
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
```

Comment: What's the problem?) You need to `addItem` method?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a method like addItem(YourDataType) and then call it:

```
if (mAdapter != null) {
        mAdapter.addItem(0, whatever);
        mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(0)
        mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
}
```

Documentation of RecyclerView.Adapter: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html
Introduction to RecyclerView and Card View: https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html